# Detect change in another sheet and update current sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet "Sheet1" that contains a form in a modal. When this modal form of sheet "Sheet1" is filled out and the "send" button is clicked, the data is inserted in sheet "Sheet2" and in sheet "Sheet3".

I would like to know how I can make it so that, being located on the "sheet1" sheet, after filling out and submitting the modal form, when the data has been inserted in the "Sheet3" sheet, without leaving the "Sheet1" sheet, this change is detected in the sheet "Sheet3" and then execute a function that will cause the sheet "Sheet1" to be updated with the data from the sheet "Sheet3".

After doing several tests, I can't get it to work.

This is my code.

```
function actualizarTareasCalendarioDesdeLogTareas(e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
      var row5 = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();

      var editedsheet = e.source.getSheetName()

      if(editedsheet == sheet){

        if (row5 != ''){
          añadirNuevasTareasAlCalendario();
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with data? Also, have you considered adding the data to Sheet1 at the same time as Sheet2 and Sheet3? It looks like you're trying to detect the change with a trigger, but `onEdit()` is only triggered by [user edits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), not by scripts. Your best option would be along the lines of including Sheet1 in your original script, but I cannot give you a concrete example without knowing how it already works.

Comment: By modal form do you mean Google Form or an html dialog that you created yourself.

Comment: If you use a google form then you can use onFormSubmit.  If it's a custtom dialog then you can do it with google.script.run or a webapp.  You have to be more clear about what you want.